# How to relink “Log in to Reply.” link

Tags: wordpress

Guys I need to relink the Log in link to some other link on WordPress. Help pls ty :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this hook to modify link

```
if ( ! function_exists( 't5_do_not_ask_for_comment_log_in' ) ) {

 add_filter( 'comment_reply_link', 't5_do_not_ask_for_comment_log_in' ); /** * Replaces the log-in link with an empty string. * * @param string $link * @return string */
 function t5_do_not_ask_for_comment_log_in( $link ) { 
     if ( empty ( $GLOBALS['user_ID'] ) && get_option( 'comment_registration' ) ) { 
         return ''; // add your link here 
        } 
        return $link; 

     } 

 }
```

Comment: Thanks @Rajdeep Singh Hundal